# querySelector with trigger click not working into angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

querySelector not working with click() method on angular 
it throws compilation error :

> 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'

```
document.body.querySelector(".class").click();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is missing a lot of details but can you try to explicitly cast it as an HTMLElement:

```
let yourElem= <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.class');
yourElem.click();
```

Comment: Thank you that solve my problem, my question was short because it doesn't need more details I wanted just to add this trigger click on a simple method